# MVC c# AngularJS adding of two values not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, I have a form which has two numeric textboxes and I want to display sum of them:

```
    <div ng-app>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PS_Fees, new { @ng_model = "PSFees", @class = "form-control DMPClientAccountNew", @type = "number", @step = "any" })
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DMPFees, new { @ng_model = "DMPFees", @class = "form-control DMPClientAccountNew", @type = "number", @step = "any" })
<div>    {{ PSFees + DMPFees   }}</div>
    </ div>
```

The output displays `{{ PSFees + DMPFees }}`

I don't understand why, because I don't want to add any more complicated script into this page?

Comment: The output of what displays `{{ PSFees + DMPFees }}`?. You don't seem to have any angular javascript code at all. Can you provide a minimal code example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example that reproduces the problem, within your question and not as a comment.

Comment: @ben-robinson updated